# <failed to convert exception to string> <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope"></div>

Tags: angularjs, laravel, angular-routing

I have been having this problem with continues loading with this error on the Chrome Dev tools

Here are my Resource Files structures

resources

```
 |--assets
    |--js
      |--app.js
      |--bootstrap.js
    |--sass
 |--lang
 |--views
    |--index.php
    |--login.php
```

here is my app.js code

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('angular');
require('angular-route');

var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(["$routeProvider",'$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when("/login", {
            templateUrl : "../../views/login.php"
        })
        .otherwise("/", {
            templateUrl : "views/index.php"
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
           });
    }
]);
```

Here is my index.php

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
<script src="js/manifest.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<base href="/">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<p><a href="/">home</a></p>
<a href="/login">login</a>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

I am trying to do an angularjs routing on resources although I tried it in the public folder.

[image]

I added my routes/web.php for further evaluation of the error.

```
 Route::any('{path?}', function()
 {
    return View::make('index');
 })->where("path", ".+");
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I added the screenshot of my problem.

Comment: Are you sure angular is loaded properly with require()?

Comment: Cuse all your require() seams to be failing

Comment: Yes because I performed a simple Hello world to see if the angular is properly loaded.

Comment: Try <ng-view></ng-view>  no div

Comment: the same error but if I removed the ng-view there is no error

Comment: Where do you call the controller for your view? if any.

Comment: i also tried adding a controller on the same file just to see if that would help but still the same problem .

Comment: How did you say hello world? Plain Javascript or in your scope or something?

Comment: Look into your require().  Are you loading them as module?

Comment: here is my angular versions if it helps "angular": "^1.6.9", "angular-route": "^1.6.9"

Comment: before requiring angular-route i tested if the required are working just fine using scope